# argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python

Добрый день, после переустановки винды перестал работать скрипт, выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\bla\bla\script\logger.py", line 146, in <module>
    run_traces(args.Addr, args.user, args.password, args.dirname, args.diag, arg
s.stdout)
  File "C:\bla\bla\script\logger.py", line 55, in run_traces
    if 'clog' in device.get_http_info():
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Подскажите плиз как это можно понять/интерпретировать?

Answer (score 2):

Это никак не связано с переустановкой винды.

Оператор `in` проверяет нахождение подстроки в строке (`'foo' in 'foobar'`) или элемента внутри итерируемого объекта (`'foo' in ['foo', 'bar']`).

Буквально ошибка переводится так: `NoneType` не является итерируемым типом. Возникает она тогда, когда к объекту `None` пытаются применить операцию, характерную для итерируемых объектов (например, списков, кортежей, словарей и др.)

В данном случае у вас метод `device.get_http_info()` вернул `None`, и получилось выражение вида `'clog' in None`, что явно ошибка.

Что с этим делать - смотреть что за метод `get_http_info` (читать документацию), смотреть в каких случаях этот метод возвращает `None`, обрабатывать эти случаи в скрипте.

Советы: пробуйте переводить текст ошибки, читайте документацию, не верьте в магию переустановки винды.